# How to make Adobe Illustrator remember past colors

Tags: adobe-illustrator, color

I use the live paint tool - but between each selection the color palette gets reset. How can I make it remember the last color I chose?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

According to a post on the Adobe forums, this is not possible:

> No way to make Illustrator remember the settings - they programmed it
>   as bad as it is and I don't think there is a way at least using the
>   UI.

[Source](https://forums.adobe.com/thread/1070208?start=0&tstart=0)

Comment: That forum post is about something completely different...